# Java sockets act strange

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I have a TCP server application in Java. When client connects, it tries to read packet from the connection. However, it does read even if the client didn't send anything. What I get is aray of bytes initialized by 0. I expected the socket to wait, and eventually timeout, until some data comes.
However, instead it acts strange like this.
What's wrong with this and how I can fix it?
Here's how I read from the socket:

```
byte bytes[] = new byte[25];
socket.getInputStream().read(commandBytes);
```

Comment: Can we see the code, that does the reading?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.read` returns the number of bytes read. You need to check it before using the buffer. In your case, it is, probably, `-1`, meaning, that the client has not sent any data

Comment: A return value of -1 means the peer has closed the connection.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Closed the connection without sending any data.

Answer (score -1):

> What I get is aray of bytes initialized by 0.

What you get is a return value from the `read()` method that tells you how many bytes  were read, or -1 indicating end of stream, i.e. that the peer has closed the connection. As you are ignoring this value, your code isn't correct.

> I expected the socket to wait, and eventually timeout, until some data comes.

As you aren't setting a timeout, it won't timeout: it will block until data arrives or end of stream occurs.

> However, instead it acts strange like this.

There is nothing strange about it, except your expectations.